# How do you find if the line integral is independent of path?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Show that the given integral is independent of a path. How do I do this?
Then, evaluate the line integral $I$ by finding a potential function $f$ and applying the fundamental theorem of line integrals.
Can someone please help I am so lost in this...

$$I = \int_{(0, 0)}^{(0, 2)} (x + y)\,dx + (x - y)\,dy$$

Comment: Show that the integrated form is exact. Independence of the chosen path means that the integral over every closed path is $0$. The simplest way to show that is to find a potential. (In this case.)

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Find a function $f$ with $\partial f/\partial x = x+y$ and $\partial f/\partial y =x-y$.

Comment: but they do not equal. dont they have to equal each other

Comment: No, the mixed second derivatives need to be equal (for sufficiently regular $f$), $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$, which is equivalent to the form being _closed_ [which in turn implies that it is _locally_ exact].

Comment: so all i would have to do is take the second derivative and then say it is a integral is independent of a path?

Comment: No. If you have a form $g\,dx + h\,dy$, then $\partial g/\partial y = \partial h/\partial x$ is a **necessary** condition for the integral to depend only on the endpoints of the path, but (in general) not a sufficient condition.

Comment: then what do i have to do?

Comment: I think what @DanielFischer is saying is that a **necessary** condition for a line integral of $fdx+gdy$ to be independent of path is that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and a **sufficient condition** for a line integral of $fdx+gdy$ to be independent of path is that there exists a function $h$ with $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=f$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=g$. In particular, what you can do to answer your question is to find a function $h$ such that $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=x+y$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=x-y$ (as Daniel states above).

Comment: *Hint*: By partial integration with respect to $x$ of the equation $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=x+y$, we find that $h=\frac{x^2}{2}+xy+f(y)$ for some function $f$ of $y$. By partial integration with respect to $y$ of the equation $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=x-y$, we find that $h=xy-\frac{y^2}{2} + g(x)$ for some function $g$ of $x$. How should we define $f$ and $g$ so that $\frac{x^2}{2}+xy+f(y)=xy-\frac{y^2}{2}+g(x)$? If you find $f$ and $g$ such that this is the case, then $h$ can be taken as either of the two sides of the equality in the last line and $h$ will be a potential function.

Comment: I am still lost, any other ideas?

Comment: @jainsmit Please see my answer below ...

Answer (score 2):

Define the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-\frac{y^2}{2}$. Prove that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=x+y$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x-y$. In the language of your question, $f$ is a potential function.

Now, you want to integrate

$\int_{(0,0)}^{(0,2)} (x-y)dx+(x+y)dy$

$=\int_{(0,0)}^{(0,2)} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)dx + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)dy$

and this is always zero by the fundamental theorem of line integrals. (If you're still stuck, then look up the definition of "potential function" and the fundamental theorem of line integrals.)

Comment: how do you say it is a potential function by what u showed at the beginning?

Comment: @jainsmit If you're considering the line integral of $a(x,y)dx + b(x,y)dy$, then a **potential function** is defined to be a function $f$ for which $a=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $b=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. In our case, we're trying to compute a line integral of $(x-y)dx + (x+y)dy$ so $a(x,y)=x-y$ and $b(x,y)=x+y$. Finally, as I showed above $a=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $b=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ if $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-\frac{y^2}{2}$. In other words, $f$ is a potential function. Does that answer your question?

Comment: is the answer -2 for the integral?

Comment: @jainsmit Yes, it is given by $f(0,2)-f(0,0)$ by the fundamental theorem of line integrals and as you correctly state, $f(0,2)-f(0,0)=-2$.